# Retroactively geotag photos

Tags: photos.app, ios, camera, geolocation

On my iPhone, I normally turn off Location Services on the Camera for privacy.

I turned it in today for a specific event, but not before I had taken several photos without location information.

How can I retroactively fill in the location information? I know exactly where each photo was taken, and even have pins bookmarked in Maps for each location.

It needs to be lossless, no JPEG recompression. An iOS app would be nice, or a Windows/Mac solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can geotag photos in iPhoto or Aperture on the Mac. If you sync them to your iPhone/iPad you'll also see the geolocations.

To do this on the iPhone/iPad itself, iPhoto for iOS may also let you do this (I don't have it to check). If not, you could try something 3rd-party like [PinApp](http://www.tinbert.com/PinApp/Info.html), though this will not modify the files in your Photostream (since Apple don't allow that), but can make a geotagged **copy**, which you can save (and then perhaps delete the un-tagged original?)

Once geo-tagged, it depends exactly where (in what application/device) you want the photo to be visible on the Map. iPhoto/Aperture can sync (via iTunes) with your iOS device to store photo albums on it (which will include geolocation info). And obviously the iOS apps let you save back to your camera roll and/or photo stream.

You could probably also email it to yourself or otherwise copy it back to your iPhone photo-stream if that's where you want it...

Comment: I don't have access to my Mac right now. All I have for the time being is my iPhone and iPad.

Comment: found an app that might help (see edit) - i think you'll be limited to creating geotagged copies from your photos, since I'm fairly sure Apple don't allow destructive editing of files on your iPhone/iPad, but that may be enough...?

Comment: I've added another paragraph to my question explaining what I'd like to see. If you can post an option for Windows and iOS in addition to iPhoto/Aperture for Mac, I'll gladly take your answer :)

Comment: @ERJ, Did you read my answer? I included two recommendations for iOS. I think iTunes can sync JPEG images from folders as photo albums... so any geotagging software will do (there's no advantage to specifically integrated software), but not using Windows I'm not familiar with any to recommend. I'd suggest you look on the Photography SE for Windows apps; since this is the Apple SE you probably won't get a lot of Windows users.